# Frontend + Backend Project on vercel returning 500 error to api but working on local

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, next.js, vercel

#### Summary

What I am trying to do is make frontend and backend in single project because at the first place it is seperated.

This is my code in front end this is how i sent it to backend:

```
        //Send to server end 
        const response = await fetch(`/api/chat_pro/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                prompt: toSend,
                custom_api: null,
                bot_type: typeValue,
            })
        })
```

this is what inside the backend located at /pages/api/chat_pro

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        try {
            const prompt = req.body.prompt;
            const bot_type = req.body.bot_type;
            const API_KEY = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
            
            const configuration = new Configuration({
                apiKey: API_KEY,
            });
        
            const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
        
            const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
                model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                messages: [
                    {role: "system", content: `You are a ${bot_type} assistant.` },
                    ...prompt
                ],
                temperature: 0.2,
                max_tokens: 250,
                top_p: 1,
                frequency_penalty: 0,
                presence_penalty: 0,
            });

            console.log(response.data.choices[0].message.content)
            res.status(200).send({
                bot: response.data.choices[0].message.content
            });

        
        } 
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            res.status(500).send(error || 'Something went wrong, please try again.');
        }

    }
    else{
        res.status(200).send({
        message: '- Last Update April 9, 2023',
        });
    }

}
```

Everything is working fine on local however on the vercel it is throwing this error in the logs:
[image: Screenshot_4]

#### Additional information

```js
next: ^12.0.9
openai: ^3.2.1
react: 17.0.2
Node: 18
```

Should successfully prompt on the backend and return the value to front end

Comment: try find a postman and hit the server with your api and see what happens

Comment: i tried that with ThunderClient and it is throwing 500 response status with a response bod html error code 401 which is unauthorize but i haven't set any authorization in the api.

Now that you have mentioned that again i realize that i haven't set my process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY yet. im so crazyy haha well that reminder helped me thank you

Comment: that's a good approach @Novacore ;) When in doubt, just find a way to only test part of the app, this way can help you narrow down the problem quicker